# Rim joists sitting on top of notched post

Tags: deck, safety, joists, support

My older deck doesn’t have a beam. Instead, the rim joist is attached to the 4x4 posts, most of which are notched and serve as both support for the rim joist and continue up as   railing posts.

I noticed on one post, the rim joist ends on top of the post and abuts a second span of joist. It seems like there isn’t much of the joist actually sitting on the post  and I was wondering what should be done to ensure the rim joist can’t pull away and fall off the post.

Both joists are currently nailed to the post and I just screwed two structural screws through the joists and post.

Here’s a picture
[image]

Comment: "*I just screwed two structural screws through the joists and post*"  And you are still worried it will "fall off" ?

Comment: It does not look like the post is notched, but it does look like the "rim joist" is notched (actually that looks like it is serving as a *beam* because it is supporting the perpendicular deck joists, so technically I would call that an "outside beam"... not a "rim joist") You are correct in worrying because typically the beam bears (fully) on a notch in the post. It looks like the whole load of your deck surface is being carried by the thinnest parts of your notched "outside beams". This is atypical and is not how decks are currently built.

Comment: I'm clearly not a framing expert at all, so this only a comment/suggestion:  Would it be possible/practical to sister on some 2x material on 3 sides of the post, under the beam or rim joist or whatever its properly called, make it pretty long and screw the heck out of it (maybe even add some epoxy glue) to "manufacture" notches that would support the beam/rim joint?  Yeah, it's a patch job and this is only a suggestion from a non-expert.

Comment: they would be called ledgers, and yes that possible, probably doesn't need to be particularly long.

Comment: Jimmy Fix-it, thanks for the info. The inner board to which the perpendicular joists are attached ends where it meets the post in the image, and a new board starts and continues on the other side of the post. So it is not notched and none of its weight is carried on the post. Only the outer board actually sits on the post (it’s hard to see but the post is definitely notched as I can follow it up to above the deck surface).